# How to ceate my own user type using jadira usertype

Tags: java, hibernate, usertype

I have my class MyClass that can be seralized/deserialized to/from string.

I looking for a simplest way use it as a hibernate property and serialize using jadira.

```
class MyClass {
    @ToString
    public String toString() {}

    @fromString
    public static MyClass fromString(String encoded) {}
}
```

And then, use it in an entity

```
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype....") 
    private MyClass field;
}
```

My question is what should I write inside @Type?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

@TypeDef(name="BoundType", typeClass="org.jadira.usertype.bindings.PersistentBoundClass")

....

@Type(type = "BoundType", parameters = { @Parameter(name="javaClass", value="MyClass"), @Parameter(name="hibernateClass", value="java.lang.String.class")})